Excel Power Query - Returning multiple tables from single query
I have a web query which is expensive (time consuming) to run and I wish to return multiple processed tables (e.g. 3 tables) within the same query, and display the results to separate sheets?
Is this possible? The reason I don’t want to use separate queries is that there are overheads in each web query call, making it slow to run. Thank you
E.g.
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="WEB_QUERY"]}[Content],
...
table1 = <>
Table2 = <>
Table3 = <>
in
Table1
Return multiple tables within same query

"Is this possible?" No. But you may be able to use one query to get the data, and then have three queries using that one query as the data source. Or perhaps you could use partitions.

Make sure the three source tables are named so you can easily reference them as =Table1 or similar. Then add another sheet to the source workbook and reference the three source tables one next to another, all starting in row 1. You can then query this sheet just once and you get all three tables in one go. Reference this query in PQ to split it in three new queries, which you load after the desired transformations.
